# Nested Circle Measurement using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to find the distance between nested Circles shown in below image from all four sides (Left, Right, Top, Bottom) using Matlab. I found this circles using `imfindcircle`.

Here is the Image:

[image: OpticCupDisc Image]

Comment: If you used `imfindcircle`, then you have the centers and the radii of the circles. From there it's just arithmetic. If you're having trouble coding a solution, post your code as well as *which* distance you're talking about (min, max, mean, all distances?).

Comment: Yes I have both values but I don't know how can I use it. I need to find distance between edges of inside circle from outside circle from all side (top, bottom, left, right)

Comment: Have you looked into distance measures e.g. [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html)?

Comment: Ok I will get a try on it ..

Comment: You can use _imdistline_

Answer (score 0):

You may follow something like this. First, remove the white background from the image. I have taken center of circle here using *ginput*, I assume you sought the circles using *imfindcircle*, so you should be having the centers in hand. Using the center coordinates, I will frame the extreme points, top, left, bottom and right and then I will calculate the distance between these points and center.

```
rgbImage = imread('JjkrL.jpg') ;
%% Remove the white background
grayImage = min(rgbImage, [], 3);
binaryImage = grayImage < 200;
binaryImage = bwareafilt(binaryImage, 1);
[rows, columns] = find(binaryImage);
row1 = min(rows);
row2 = max(rows);
col1 = min(columns);
col2 = max(columns);
% Crop
croppedImage = rgbImage(row1:row2, col1:col2, :);
[nx,ny,t] = size(croppedImage) ;
imshow(croppedImage) ;
%%
% Centers of circles
C1 = [84  142] ;
C2 = [76 136] ;

%% Get distances
% circle 1/ Big circle
% Edge points
top = [C1(1) 1] ;
bottom = [C1(1) nx] ;
left = [1 C1(2)] ;
right = [ny C1(2)] ;
pts = [top ;left ;bottom ; right] ;

hold on
plot(C1(1),C1(2),'*r')
plot(pts(:,1),pts(:,2),'*k') ;
%% Get distances
data = repmat(C1,[length(pts),1])-pts ;
dist = sqrt(data(:,1).^2+data(:,2).^2);
```